# rasterio what to do when nodata value is present in data

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I have a geotiff raster (uint8 datatype) that I'm reading in with rasterio and then cropping with a polygon.

But the issue is that all pixels outside the polygon should be considered nodata in the final cropped image. But, I'm not sure what nodata value to use because my raster contains most values. So if I set the nodata value to be 0 for example, there would be 0 values within the raster itself that would be marked as nodata, even though they shouldn't be.

So is there some way to set the mask without caring what the actual data value at that pixel is? Ideally I could just set mask values to some special number that I know no data value would have.

Or is the only way to convert my uint8 raster to a float32, and set the nodata to be `nan`? Would there be any side effects from doing this data type conversion on a raster?

Comment: Are you attempting to crop the image or apply a mask? If you want to crop the image, you would be transforming it so the extent of the image matches the extent of the polygon. If you want to apply a mask, any values outside of the extent of the polygon get a nodata value. Happy to help with an answer depending on the workflow you're after!

Comment: @JmeCS I'm applying a mask, so values outside the polygon get a nodata value. But my raster is a uint8, so what nodata value would I use?

Comment: If you want to stick with uint8, values will need to be between 0 and 255. You say you have true 0 values in your dataset, do I'd recommend setting nodata to 255. If you have "true" 255 values, I'd recommend converting to a different datatype, e.g. int or float and setting to, e.g. -9999